# I would like to change the login logo Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have this problem, and I don't know how to change the odoo logo from login page, I override `update_login` function

```
update_logo: function(reload) {
        var company = session.company_id;
        var img = session.url('/web/static/src/img/logo2.png' + '?db=' + session.db + (company ? '&company=' + company : ''));
        this.$('.o_sub_menu_logo img').attr('src', '').attr('src', img + (reload ? "#" + Date.now() : ''));
        this.$('.oe_logo_edit').toggleClass('oe_logo_edit_admin', session.is_superuser);
```

but isn't work, please help (Sorry for my english)

Comment: How did you override this method? Did you go straight and change it from the server files or in a different way?

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas I went directly to the configuration file and edited it manually

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to change the logo appeared while login into odoo database.

This logo come from res.company I mean Your Company 
try to change logo of Company It will reflect in login screen.

To do that goto > settings > Users > Companies > Change Logo image of Company.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `addons/web/views/webclient_templates.xml` and find the template with the id `web.login_layout`, it should be around line 215. There is an element there:

```
<img t-attf-src="/web/binary/company_logo{{ '?dbname='+db if db else '' }}"/>
```

Change that to:

```
<img t-attf-src="/web/static/src/img/logo2.png{{ '?dbname='+db if db else '' }}"/>
```

and press control + shift + R on your browser to refresh.

Your logo should be in place.

Comment: Thanks but it does not change i add  <img t-attf-src="/web/static/src/img/logo.png{{ '?dbname='+db if db else '' }}"/> that but isn't work logo.png and logo2.png it's same

Comment: Iooking the font code on web with f12 not change <img src="/web/binary/company_logo"> :s

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. To clarify my initial misunderstandings of this post. The line of code above provided from George Daramouskas, indicates the location of the photo you want to present in the login screen.

He is right. You need to move your photo into /addons/web/src/img/ directory path first.

Then you need to update that line of code in webclient_
templates.xml as `<img t-attf-src="/web/static/src/img/<name of photo>.<file type> {{ '?dbname='+db if db else '' }}"/>`